# Laravel sqlsrv - unable to create timestamps()

Tags: laravel

I am migrating an existing projekt in L5.1.x to a new server running with Server 2012 and an SQL Server 2012.

I have some problems when using the timestamps() fields for tables. When ill add in my Scheme:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Ill get the created_at and updated_at column with type "datetime".

But with that new configuration when ill try to add a Model to this database i am always getting that error:

```
QueryException: Unable to convert an nvarchar Value to and datetime Value ....
```

When ill disable the timestamp fields in my Model, everything is working:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

.. but of course no values for created_at and updated_at

I dont know what cause this problem - any ideas? i could manually set the created_at and updated_at field to "GETDATE()" - but i would like to use Laravels base functionality.

Comment: In your connection settings, you are setting the driver to `sqlsrv` and you have the default connection setup correctly?

Comment: Of course they are - ill already found the problem (after 10 hours) ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok ill found the problem - Laravel creates a datetime with format of:

```
"Y-m-d H:i:s.u"
```

But the SQL Server wants the format of:

```
"Y-d-m H:i:s"
```

So when you update your model function with:

```
public function fromDateTime($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse(parent::fromDateTime($value))->format('Y-d-m H:i:s');
}
```

You are able to convert to date format to the correct value for your SQL Server ( dont know why its Y-d-m, its not my server ;) )